# dictionary: Unique relative values where values are of list type

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, nlp, tensorflow, text-classification

I am getting the output of word2vec_basic.py in the following format

Nearest to key1  : node1, node2, node3 ..
Nearest to key2 : node2, node4, node5 ..

This implies that node2 is comparatively closer to key2 over key1 (Please correct me if I am wrong, as I am newbie here)

It would be great if I get the output in the following format

Nearest to key1  : node1, node3 , node6..
Nearest to key2 : node2, node4, node5 ..

That is, consider only the closest neighbor for clustering.

Suggestions for the same?

I am maintaining a python dictionary for the same of the following format:

```
{
key1: [node1,node2,node3],
key2: [node2,node4,node5]
}
```

But I required,

```
 {
    key1: [node1,node3,node6],
    key2: [node2,node4,node5]
    }
```

And for the above dictionary, I will  be needing

```
Nearest to key1  : node1, node3 , node6..
Nearest to key2 : node2, node4, node5 ..
```

Could we do this in tensorflow itself, or should I define a function which takes dictionary as input and give me the required output?

For eg:
If we have a python dictionary of the following format:

```
{ 
   a: ["abc","bcd","def"],
   b: ["def","xyz"]
}
```

Here the values are list. I am looking for the following format from the above input:

```
{ 
    a: ["abc","bcd"],
    b: ["def","xyz"]
}
```

Suggestions are welcome on how I could achieve it.

Also, are there any python in built functions which could help me to reach the above output format?

Comment: why not remove def from b?

Comment: Why wasn't `"def"` left in `a` and removed from `b`—values relative to what—what is it exactly you're trying to achieve? It's especially unclear since you haven't included any code that could have provided some additional clues.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain how it is required

Comment: Your update helps clarify what you want to do—and I've submitted an answer based on it. Please try it out and provide some feedback.

Comment: Related to above question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295791/classification-using-tensorflow-word2vec-basic

Answer (score 0):

*dicts* are unordered so which dupe gets removed is not guaranteed but you can keep a *set* of elements seen so far as you iterate over the items, updating/removing elements from the list/value if it has already been *seen*:

```
d = {
  "a": ["abc","bcd","def"],
   "b": ["def","xyz"]
}
seen = set()
for k,v in d.items():
    d[k] = [seen.add(ele) or ele for ele in v if ele not in seen]

print(d)
```

This could output:

```
{'b': ['def', 'xyz'], 'a': ['abc', 'bcd']}
```

Or:

```
 d = { "a": ["abc","bcd","def"], "b": ["xyz"]}
```

It completely depends on which key you hit first.

As you can see from [this top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/2141635) with 436 upvotes, the removal logic is efficient and it maintains the order if required.  To also to avoid the *set.add* lookup each time as in the link, you can set  `seen_add = seen.add` and use `seen._add(ele)` in place of `seen.add`.

Comment: To make this work you're relying on 2 obscure properties of the python language (implementation). Why not break up your into 3 lines that any 1st year cs major could understand?

Comment: @BiRico,  you downvoted  working efficient code, well done. The OP asked for a way to do it, I provided it. Should I add a less efficient way?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks ! That seems nice.. I am also exploring tensorflow, if we could do it in word2vec_basic( I have updated my question with how I am using it )..though your solution is equally good ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Since dictionaries entries in Python are unordered, you need to first build a separate dictionary keyed by node recording each list (or sequence) it's in as well as its index in that list so relative distances in each list can be compared to one another. After that's done, it can be referenced to determine whether each node should stay in each list it is in or not by making a second pass through the dictionary's contents.

```
d = {
   "a": ["abc", "bcd", "def"],
   "b": ["def", "xyz"]
}

def check_usage(k, elem_usage):
    if len(elem_usage) == 1:  # unique?
        return True
    else:
        index = elem_usage[k]  # within this elem's seq
        for key,value in elem_usage.items():
            if key != k:
                if value < index:
                    return False
        else:
            return True

usage = {}
for key in d:  # build usage dictionary
    for index, item in enumerate(d[key]):
        usage.setdefault(item, {})[key] = index

for k,seq in d.items()::  # remove nodes that are closer in other lists
    d[k] = [elem for elem in seq if check_usage(k, usage[elem])]

# display results
print('{')
for k in sorted(d):
    print('    {!r}: {},'.format(k, d[k]))
print('}')
```

Output:

```
{                      
    'a': ['abc', 'bcd'],
    'b': ['def', 'xyz'],
}
```